# "Install overnight" option does not apply update over night

Tags: updates, 7.0-nougat

When an update to the android is available, there are three options what to do with it:

- Install now
- Install overnight
- Later

When I select "Install overnight", the notification bar says: "Update will be installed between 2 AM and 5 AM automatically." However, next morning, nothing is installed.

What's the problem here, can't the phone read the clock? How can I fix it to enable the automatic installation overnight?

- Android 7.0
- Samsung Galaxy XCover 4

Comment: If it is a security update, there wont have any change in UI. please check for any change in android security patch level in settings. If its an OS update, then there will have some UI change.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your software did not update?

Try to check it.

Open `Settings-About Phone-Software Information`

Check *Security Software Version* and *Android Security Patch Level* as well.

In Security Software Version, month of installed software is mentioned.

**Why software not updated overnight ?**

Well, this may be due to these possible reasons:

• Your device battery was running low that time.

• You have enabled any type of battery saver.